# jQuery sortable not posting on appended li

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a form appending to a **ul** from a php ajax response

```
    $('#page-form form').submit(function() {

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        //alert(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "newPage.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $('.item1 ul').append(html).slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

And using .sortable to order the **li** an save the position

```
$(function() {
    $(".item1 ul").sortable({ revert:true, update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
        $.post("pageOrder.php", order, function(theResponse){

        });
    }
    });
});
```

The problem is the appended html does not post to pageOrder.php

Comment: I found the problem. My appended html from the php script was not echoing the id.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this.

```
$('#page-form form').submit(function()
{
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "newPage.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('.item1 ul').append(html).slideDown();
            $(".item1 ul").sortable(
            {
                revert:true,
                update: function()
                {
                    var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
                    $.post("pageOrder.php", order, function(theResponse){  });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This way because you are appending new `dom` to `.item ul` so `newly appended DOM` do not have `event` assigned to them.

Install [**FireQuery**](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) a Firebug extension for jQuery development which allows you to see jQuery code and events attached to `dom` .